# EXPO SDK 48 - DeepLinks with android 13 doesn't open with QR Code

Tags: android, react-native, expo, android-deep-link

I'm currently with an expo/react native project and I ejected my app to be able to do some of the code natively.
So I have in my AndroidManifest.xml a part of code for DeepLinks but since the new Expo SDK, it no longer works on Android 13.

Any ideas ?

AndroidManifest.xml :
[AndroidManifest.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K3kT.png)

I tested on Android 11 and it works fine. And on my Android 13 the link is recognized when I go to the settings of my application because I can add it by hand but it is no longer put automatically.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I removed the scheme useless for my app (all except https and my website) and Google Play will accept my redirection.
I also removed the "pathPattern", maybe it's also the problem.

Bye